# Android need help to pinch zoom on a image view

Tags: java, android, pinchzoom

i'm a new Android Developer and i'm struggling a bit with Pinch Zoom on a ImageView. This code was from a previous app that i'm modifying to my needs. My java knowledge is really poor.

```js
package com.test.testappfour;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

import com.test.testappfour.TouchImageView;

import com.test.testappfour.R;

public class FloodFillActivity extends SherlockActivity{

 public static final String IMG = null;
 Context con;
 public Bitmap currentbmp;
 private String imgfile;
 public int replacecolor;
 public ImageView showcolor;
 private AdView mAdView;
 // ImageButton btnsave,btnshare,btnreset;

 public FloodFillActivity()
 {
  replacecolor = 0xffff0000;
  imgfile = null;
  currentbmp = null;
 }
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.floodfill);
  getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
  getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#ffcf28")));
  getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
  getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);

  con = this;
  mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adViewad);
  mAdView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder()
    .build());
   
  imgfile = getIntent().getStringExtra(IMG);
  //  btnsave=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ibtnSave);
  //  btnshare=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ibtnShare);
  //  btnreset=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ibtnReset);

  ImageView imageview = (TouchImageView)findViewById(R.id.floodfill);
  ImageView imageview1 = (TouchImageView)findViewById(R.id.colorpal);
  showcolor = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.showcolor);
  showcolor.setBackgroundColor(replacecolor);

  try
  {
   imageview.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromStream(getAssets().open(imgfile), null));
   imageview1.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromStream(getAssets().open("CATIMAGE/color.png"), null));
   imageview1.setOnTouchListener(new android.view.View.OnTouchListener() {

    Bitmap pmap;
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionevent)
    {
     try
     {
      Point point = new Point();
      point.x = (int)motionevent.getX();
      point.y = (int)motionevent.getY();
      ImageView imageview2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.colorpal);
      imageview2.buildDrawingCache();
      pmap = imageview2.getDrawingCache();
      replacecolor = pmap.getPixel(point.x, point.y);
      showcolor.setBackgroundColor(replacecolor);
     }
     catch (Exception exception) { }
     return true;
    }



   });


  } catch (Exception exception) { }


  imageview.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

   Bitmap bmap;
   @Override
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {
     Point point = new Point();
     point.x = (int)event.getX();
     point.y = (int)event.getY();
     ImageView imageview2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.floodfill);
     if (bmap == null)
     {
      imageview2.buildDrawingCache();
      bmap = imageview2.getDrawingCache();
     }
     int i = bmap.getPixel(point.x, point.y);
     int j = replacecolor;
     (new TheTask(bmap, point, i, j, imageview2)).execute(new Void[0]);

    }
    return true;
   }
  });
 }
 
 

 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
  inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
  return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem)
 {       

  ImageView imageview2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.floodfill);
  final String s ="Image_"+String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
  switch (menuItem.getItemId()) 
  {
  case android.R.id.home: 
   onBackPressed();
   return true;
  case R.id.save:
   if (currentbmp == null)
   {
    imageview2.buildDrawingCache();
    currentbmp = imageview2.getDrawingCache();
   }
   Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), currentbmp, s, null);
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Save to Gallery", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   return true;

  case R.id.share:

   if (currentbmp == null)
   {
    imageview2.buildDrawingCache();
    currentbmp = imageview2.getDrawingCache();
   }

   String share =Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), currentbmp, s, null);
   Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.SEND");
   intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.SUBJECT", "Test!");
   intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.STREAM", Uri.parse(share));
   intent.setType("image/jpeg");
   startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Testttttt"));

   return true;

  case R.id.repeat:
   try
   {
    Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(getAssets().open(imgfile), null);
    imageview2.setImageDrawable(drawable);
    imageview2.buildDrawingCache();
   }
   catch (IOException ioexception1)
   {
    ioexception1.printStackTrace();
   }
   return true;
   
  case R.id.rateapp:
   
   final String appName = getPackageName();//your application package name i.e play store application url
   try {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
      Uri.parse("market://details?id="
        + appName)));
   } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
    startActivity(new Intent(
      Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
      Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="
        + appName)));
   }
   return true;
   
  default:
   return super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
  }

 }
}
```

This is a fill color activity for black and white images (coloring book app), and i've used MikeOrtiz TouchImageView to implement pinch to zoom. I've just changed this lines 70-71:

```js
  ImageView imageview = (TouchImageView)findViewById(R.id.floodfill);
  ImageView imageview1 = (TouchImageView)findViewById(R.id.colorpal);

to

  TouchImageView imageview = (TouchImageView)findViewById(R.id.floodfill);
  TouchImageView imageview1 = (TouchImageView)findViewById(R.id.colorpal);
```

I'm getting this error:
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView cannot be cast to com.test.testappfour.TouchImageView

Can you give me a hand? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<com.test.testappfour.TouchImageView
    android:id="@+id/floodfill”
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

in your xml layout file.

**PS:** if I helped you, mark my answer as accepted and just ask separate question.